# Magento 2 not able to login to admin pane;

Tags: magento-2.1, admin-panel, composer

I just installed a plugin via composer. Note the site and admin panel worked just fine prior and the customer facing sie of the site seems to work fine. After the plugin install I then re-compiled via the command line. Now when I go to the admin panel of our Magento 2 website and enter my username and password I get an error message that says

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 1467091421105

Now when I look at that 1467091421105.log file in the report folder it says:

```
 a:4:{i:0;s:137:"The stream or file "/var/www/html/****.com/v2/var/log/debug.log" could not be opened: 
 failed to open stream: Permission denied";i:1;s:6539:"#0 /var/www/html/****.com/v2/vendor/magento/framework/Logger/Handler/Base.php(60): 
 Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
```

When I look in the exception.log file I see:

```
[2017-09-06 14:42:03] main.CRITICAL: 
Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException: Cannot read contents from file"/var/www/html/***.com/v2/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixinss.js" 

Warning!file_get_contents(/var/www/html/****.com/v2/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/****.com/v2/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:149
```

Comment: Id suggest redeploying your website php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` && `chmod 0777 -R pub var`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set right Permisions for directory, you can try this Command form SSH

```
chmod -R 777 pub; chmod -R 777 var; chmod -R 777 app/etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use commands:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
chmod -R 777 var pub generated
```

Goodluk!

Comment: this plus the answer from mahmoud worked for me. thanks!